# Kotlin getUriForFile (downloadUri) causing app to crash while launching camera from app

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

can you help me to debug my app, it builds without errors, but as soon as I click on "Change profile image" to load the camera (like the button for changing profile picture on Instagram), my app stops.

I will appreciate any help, thanks

Here is the debug:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.homeactivity, PID: 30063
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.homeactivity/files/Pictures/JPEG_20200109_040634_284139119.jpg
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    at com.example.homeactivity.activities.EditProfileActivity.takeCameraPicture(EditProfileActivity.kt:71)
    at com.example.homeactivity.activities.EditProfileActivity.access$takeCameraPicture(EditProfileActivity.kt:29)
    at com.example.homeactivity.activities.EditProfileActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(EditProfileActivity.kt:49)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

EditProfileActivity.kt

```
    package com.example.homeactivity.activities

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import com.example.homeactivity.R
import com.example.homeactivity.views.PasswordDialog
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_edit_profile.*
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PasswordDialog.Listener {

    private lateinit var mImageUri: Uri
    private lateinit var mStorage: StorageReference
    private val TAG = "EditProfileActivity"
    private lateinit var mUser: com.example.homeactivity.models.User
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mPendingUser: com.example.homeactivity.models.User
    private val TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")

        close_image.setOnClickListener { finish() }
        save_image.setOnClickListener { updateProfile() }
        change_photo_text.setOnClickListener { takeCameraPicture() }

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference

        mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListenerAdapter {
                mUser = it.getValue(com.example.homeactivity.models.User::class.java)!!
                name_input.setText(mUser.name, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                username_input.setText(mUser.username, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                website_input.setText(mUser.website, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                bio_input.setText(mUser.bio, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                email_input.setText(mUser.email, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                phone_input.setText(mUser.phone.toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            })
    }

    private fun takeCameraPicture() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            val imageFile = createImageFile()
            mImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.example.homeactivity.fileprovider",
                imageFile)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri)
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${simpleDateFormat.format(Date())}_",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
            mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            mDatabase.child("users/$uid/photo").setValue(task.result)
                                .addOnCompleteListener {
                                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: photo saved successfully")
                                    } else {
                                        showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                                    }
                                }
                        } else {
                            showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateProfile() {
        mPendingUser = com.example.homeactivity.models.User(
            name = name_input.text.toString(),
            username = username_input.text.toString(),
            website = website_input.text.toString(),
            bio = bio_input.text.toString(),
            email = email_input.text.toString(),
            phone = phone_input.text.toString()
        )
        val error = validate(mPendingUser)
        if (error == null) {
            if (mPendingUser.email == mUser.email) {
                updateUser(mPendingUser)
            } else {
                PasswordDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, "password_dialog")
            }
        } else {
            showToast(error)
        }
    }

    override fun onPasswordConfirm(password: String) {
        if (password.isNotEmpty()) {
            val credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(mUser.email, password)
            mAuth.currentUser!!.reauthenticate(credential) {
                mAuth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(mPendingUser.email) {
                    updateUser(mPendingUser)
                }
            }
        } else {
            showToast("You must enter your password")
        }
    }

    private fun updateUser(user: com.example.homeactivity.models.User) {
        val updatesMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
        if (user.name != mUser.name) updatesMap["name"] = user.name
        if (user.username != mUser.username) updatesMap["username"] = user.username
        if (user.website != mUser.website) updatesMap["website"] = user.website
        if (user.bio != mUser.bio) updatesMap["bio"] = user.bio
        if (user.email != mUser.email) updatesMap["email"] = user.email
        if (user.phone != mUser.phone) updatesMap["phone"] = user.phone

        mDatabase.updateUser(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid, updatesMap) {
            showToast("Profile saved")
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun validate(user: com.example.homeactivity.models.User): String? =
        when {
            user.name.isEmpty() -> "Please enter name"
            user.username.isEmpty() -> "Please enter username"
            user.email.isEmpty() -> "Please enter email"
            else -> null
        }

    private fun FirebaseUser.updateEmail(email: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun DatabaseReference.updateUser(
        uid: String, updates: Map<String, Any>,
        onSuccess: () -> Unit
    ) {
        child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).updateChildren(updates)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess()
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun FirebaseUser.reauthenticate(credential: AuthCredential, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also, I don't know why in the debugger it is searching for some "JPEG_20200109_040634_284139119.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue, an error occurs at file_paths.xml Instead of using `<external-files-path`
use `<external-path`